# self start not working if the bike in gear

Tags: motorcycle, starting, hero-honda

Suddenly the self start is not working if the bike is any gear. But the same works fine if neutral. My bike is hero honda CBZ.

What could be the problem? Can i rectify it myself? Or i need to take the bike to a mechanic shop to solve?

Comment: That sounds like it is working correctly- same for automatic cars so they don’t drive off...

Comment: But it was working perfectly. Bike was idle for a week. After that this is happening.

Comment: As I pointed out it sounds like it is working perfectly - you should consider the possibility that it was working incorrectly before i.e. it was not safe...

Comment: I've heard of a Hero Honda CBZ, but what is a Yamaha CBZ?

Comment: @Zaid sorry. It is honda. not yamaha. my bad.

Comment: Why would you want to start it when in-gear?

Comment: Bike getting turned off often if no accelerator given. If i am in signal or traffic and bike turned off, i used to start the bike by holding the clutch and press the self start button. But now i have to change to neutral then start the bike. Before i am doing all this at least few sound horn from vehicle behind me would test my ear drum here in india

Answer (score 1):

If you mean it isn't starting when it's in gear with the clutch disengaged, and it used to start under those conditions, check to see if there's a pin switch on the clutch lever housing that's gotten stuck. If so, then the starter won't be able to tell you've got the clutch lever pulled and will refuse to start. You should be able to fix it by spraying some light lubricant (like WD-40 or a silicone-based lube) down the shaft of the switch. Don't use anything heavy like white lithium grease.

Comment: Some bikes also have a side stand position sensors that won't let the engine start if the side stand is down. Could be an issue with that sensor.